# Getting Microsoft Calibri font on Amazon EC2 ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, jasper-reports

I am trying to use the Calibri font in JasperReports on my Amazon EC2 instance.  How can I get this to work?  I tried...

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package ttf-mscorefonts-installer is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'ttf-mscorefonts-installer' has no installation candidate
```

I need to be able to initiate a JVM from a PHP method which accesses this font for a report, but I don't have it on my server.  How can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
wget "http://cl.ly/0m3f0x0c252P3O3t190q/download/Calibri.ttf" -O "~/.fonts/Calibri.ttf"
```

This will save Calibri font to your default fonts directory, and all your apps & scripts can use it as a normal font.

Comment: Thank you, this works now if I call `java -jar myJar.jar` in bash, however if I call `exec("/usr/bin/java -jar /..myDirectory/myJar.jar", $result);` in PHP, I get the error `Font 'Calibri' is not available to the JVM. See the Javadoc for more details.`.  Why wouldn't this be available within PHP?

Comment: Furthermore, I created a jar file that prints out my fonts [as seen here](http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-get-example/available-font.shtml)  and in unix, I do see Calibri, but from php, exec or shell_exec, it isn't there.  What is happening?

Comment: Could you paste the font heandler class from your java file?

Comment: anyway I post another solution

Comment: I was able to get this to work by downloading it as you said in my /lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/lib/fonts/ directory and running `sudo fc-cache -f -v`.  Thank you!

Comment: is there a similar place to get all mscore fonts, not just calibri using wget?

Answer (score 1):

After this I recommend to delete Calibri.ttf from ~/.fonts but may work without delete...

You need to add this to your sources list which is at "`/etc/apt/sources.list`" location:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates multiverse
```

(You can edit that for e.g. `sudo nano /etc/sources.list`)

Then you can install the packege with this command from terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install -y ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

This will download & install...