# Install mscorefonts on ec2

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fonts, amazon-ec2

I am attempting to install mscorefonts on ec2, however I can't seem to find the magic combination of terminal commands to make it happen. I am using an m1.medium instance and `uname -a` returns `Linux worker 3.11.0-12-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 9 16:20:46 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

On my personal laptop running: `sudo apt-get install -y ttf-mscorefonts-installer` works fine, however on my ec2 instance I get the following error message:

`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ttf-mscorefonts-installer : Depends: defoma but it is not installable
                             Recommends: ttf-liberation but it is not installable
                             Recommends: x-ttcidfont-conf but it is not installable`

indeed, I have not been able to find a way to install any of these components. I have attempted modifying my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file with these:

`deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates multiverse`

as shown here: [Getting Microsoft Calibri font on Amazon EC2 ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12982832/getting-microsoft-calibri-font-on-amazon-ec2-ubuntu), but even after running `sudo apt-get update` I am still unsuccessful. How can I install the mscore fonts on ec2? My application needs them to function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventually I figured this out. My solution was to enable the multiverse ppa's. Here is the script that I used.

```
#font installation -- required to properly display fonts used in 
echo "deb http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy multiverse" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb-src http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy multiverse" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates multiverse" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb-src http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates multiverse" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
# preselect yes for ms EULA
echo ttf-mscorefonts-installer msttcorefonts/accepted-mscorefonts-eula select true | sudo debconf-set-selections
sudo apt-get install -y ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

This works on EC2 ubuntu as of January 2015 and my local machine running ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 3):

Adding multiverse is the key. This worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04:

```
sudo apt-add-repository multiverse && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```